# How do i create subdomain using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, subdomain, manual

My PHP Application required vhost configuration for subdomain access. While am creating user account, server will create a subdomain for particular user and then after they would access account through their subdomain.

How could i do this with codeigniter?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/basecamp-style-subdomains-with-codeigniter/ this may help you

Comment: You don't use CodeIgniter to create sub domains

Comment: You don't have to create subdomains for each user. Create just 1 subdomain to point to `*` and this to your Codeigniter folder. This way, every request that contains a subdomain goes to CodeIgniter. I have created a website like this, but not with Codeigniter.

Comment: try this tutorial on similar things https://youtu.be/518eRiSOTlY